# Add TestLab Navigation in Control Property Window in SiteCore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, multivariate-testing

I added a test in Sitecore test lab named HeroImage . I added variable and values for the test. Then i go on the page editor  where i want add the test .Then i  right click the control property window .

In Control Property Window i do not find TestLab Navigation Tab .Whereas i Saw TestLab Navigation tab in some examples for the add test in Sitecore.( http://www.experimentsincode.com/?p=165 ) .

Please suggest .

Answer (score 1):

Click on the red sitecore button on the top left, then click on "Application Options". To enable this. For some reason its not visible by default.